# Django ManyToMany field get all values from an object without a 'for'

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

Is it possible to get the values of a ManyToMany from an object without using a 'for'?

models.py

```
class Citizenship(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Citizenship"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Anexa(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text="3")
    citizenship = models.ManyToManyField(Citizenship, help_text="4")
```

I have an Anexa object with the name Alex and i have 4 citizenships for this object. I'm searching for something equivalent to this:

```
for citizenships in x.citizenship.all():
    print(citizenships.name)
```

Comment: Any reason(s) why you don't want to use a *for*?

Comment: it's hard to answer the question without knowing why you don't want to use a `for` loop. it makes no sense

Comment: Because i am making a pdf with reportlab and it's drawing 4 times the same propozition, i only need the vales from the object. 4 values in one propozition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was the answer:

```
print(', '.join(x.citizenship.values_list('name', flat=True))
```

Answer (score 7):

The closest you will get is a Values List https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list, which you would still have to loop through to print individually.

```
x.citizenship.values_list('name', flat=True)
```

Comment: You don't need a for-loop to print it: `print(', '.join(x.citizenship.values_list('name', flat=True))` should work fine.

Comment: I was going based off the example in which it appeared they wanted each printed by themselves on a new line or to be able to use them individually in later code. Ultimately if you just want to see them you could just print the result of the values_list

Comment: You can use `'\n'.join(...)` to insert newlines instead.

Comment: @HåkenLid make it as answer cause that's what i've wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to abstract away the looping you can create a method on the model:

```
class Anexa(models.Model):
    def print_citizens_names(self):
        for name in self.citizenship.values_list('name', flat=True):
            print(name)
```

Then in your codebase you can just do this:

```
x.print_citizens_names()
```